# I can not delete Objects...why?

Tags: ibm-doors

This is my piece of code:

```
void deleteObject(Object o, Module m){
 Link lnk, delLnk
 string srcModName
 // delete outgoing links
 for lnk in o -> "*" do {
    delete(lnk)
 }
 Object srcO
 Link inLnk
 for inLnk in o <- "*" do {
    srcModName = fullName source(inLnk)
    print srcModName "izena\n"
    edit(srcModName, false)
    delLnk = inLnk
    delete(delLnk)
 }
 flushDeletions()
 hardDelete(o)
}
```

It crashes on line **hardDelete(o)**, saying I cannot delete the Object because it has input links. Can someone tell me why?

Error:

> No se puede suprimir el objeto: El objeto tiene enlaces entrantes

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code:

```
 Link inLnk
 for inLnk in o <- "*" do {
    srcModName = fullName source(inLnk)
    print srcModName "izena\n"
    edit(srcModName, false)
    delLnk = inLnk
    delete(delLnk)
 }
```

Is not doing what you think it is doing. More specifically- this will only pick up Links where the source is already open, which based on you having the 'edit' command, seems to not be what you are trying to do.

```
string srcModName
for srcModName in o <- "*" do {
     edit ( srcModName , true , true , true ) 
}
Link inLnk
for inLnk in o <- "*" do {
   srcModName = fullName source(inLnk)
   print srcModName "izena\n"
   delLnk = inLnk
   delete(delLnk)
}
```

This will load each module, then delete the links. NOTE- this will not close the open (now edited) modules! I also made it open those modules in visible mode (so they can be easily saved / closed) and in standard view (to reduce computational overhead)

Good luck!